# How to use request(python) to use Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to use the Microsoft Graph API from the Request module in Python, but I was still new and didn't want to use Postman either. But I had a problem using the Request module:

1. How to select the application platform type?
2. How to fill in the redirect URL?
3. How to get refresher token and access token ?And how to renew(refresh) them?
4. How to get Tenant ID?

This is all my questions. I hope someone can help me solve them.

(This question by the machine translation, if there is a small mistake, also hope you understand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on your first question!

This is not a full answer that you might have been looking for, but take a look at the [Microsoft Graph API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api)

`After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.`

- Did you register your app? If not [here are the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2)
- In your question it looks like you're describing the flow for `get access on behalf of the user`, but what you need is `get access without a user`. In order to use the API through the requests module you need to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)